# How does fragment composition work in Relay?

Tags: relayjs, graphql, graphql-js

Let's use the TODO example. In [TodoList](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/examples/todo/js/components/TodoList.js) it(Line 81) has a fragment composed as

```
todos(status: $status, first: $limit) {
  edges {
    node {
      id,
      ${Todo.getFragment('todo')},
    },
  },
  ....
}
```

And now if I add a loop

```
this.props.viewer.todos.edges.map(edge =>
console.log(edge.node.text)
);
```

to function **renderTodos()** at Line 30, it will output **undefined**

The interesting thing is, if we add **text** to to the fragment like below

```
todos(status: $status, first: $limit) {
  edges {
    node {
      id,
      text,
      ${Todo.getFragment('todo')},
    },
  },
  ....
}
```

It actually "declared" **text** twice(declare in Todo component as well) and the loop works perfectly.

My question is, why it is not possible to get the "properties" back from a composition even though they are returned by Graphql Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to hueyp#7485 at #relay channel.

He pointed out it is an intended behaviour by design.

https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/thinking-in-relay.html#data-masking